# HTTP GET result in JSON has null fields ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, http, asp.net-web-api

I am currently learning how to write an ASP.NET Core Web API and I have a problem. I have a very primitive HTTP `Get`, and it should return all the books that are stored in a DbSet. When it returns them, all fields that store other objects or a collection of other objects, in this case `Reviews`, are set to Null.

I tried to solve the problem via `Include()`, but the same problem occurs with null fields already in the stored object.

Here are the ApiContext, User, Book, Review, and DataController classes below:

```
public class ApiContext : DbContext
{
    public ApiContext(DbContextOptions<ApiContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Review>()
                    .Property(r => r.Description)
                    .IsRequired(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
                    .HasMany(b => b.Reviews)
                    .WithOne(r => r.Book_)
                    .HasForeignKey(r => r.BookID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                    .HasMany(u => u.Reviews)
                    .WithOne(r => r.User_)
                    .HasForeignKey(r => r.UserID);                      
    }

    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Pages { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}

public class Review
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }       
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public User User_ { get; set; }
    public int BookID { get; set; }
    public Book Book_ { get; set; }
}
```

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class DataController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ApiContext _context;

    public DataController(ApiContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult AllBooks()
    {
        return new JsonResult(Ok(_context.Books.ToList()));
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone",
      "author": "J.K. Rowling",
      "description": "Book about Harry Potter's adventure 1.",
      "pages": 336,
      "reviews": null
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets",
      "author": "J.K. Rowling",
      "description": "...",
      "pages": 432,
      "reviews": null
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban",
      "author": "J.K. Rowling",
      "description": "Book about Harry Potter's adventure 3.",
      "pages": 523,
      "reviews": null
    }
  ],
  "formatters": [],
  "contentTypes": [],
  "declaredType": null,
  "statusCode": 200
}
```

I hope I'm not the only one facing this problem and I can get some help to solve it.

Comment: Two questions 1) Is the data in the database? 2) You are using Entity where there is a mapping file that maps the c# classes/properties to the database tables/fields. Is the mapping correct.  Do you need to use Migration to update the mapping?  You have a primary key ID between the book and review class.  Do you need to add the key attribute to the classes?   You have a Book ID and a User ID.  How do you distinguish between the two IDs?

Comment: If you want to get all books, including their reviews and the user in the review, you need to use `ctx.Books.Include(b => b.Reviews).ThenInclude(r => r.User)` - you need to "chain" the includes to handle all related entities - and avoid circular references (do **not** do a `ThenInclude(r => r.Book)` - that would get the book again, in a circular fashion)

Comment: @jdweng 1) Yes, data is stored in database. I use SqlServer
2) Yes, there is mapping file. But i didn't use migration. And i already tried to use attributes to fix the problem, but it didn't help.

Comment: @marc_s I tried this method and it does work. But I have a question, "Is it ok to do this when you have a quiet long chain of nested data in the objects?".

Comment: Use Migration Update to update the mapping.  Then try again.  The data may not be linked properly in the database.  If you changed the attributes you need to update the mapping.  Query the database and make sure the IDs are stored properly.

Comment: Well, *technically*, you can build quite a long chain of includes - not sure if there's a hard limit anywhere. The question is more from a usability point of view : will your users really want to see a huge long chain of entities, that contain subentities, which again contain sub-sub-entities and so forth? How "manageable" is that for your end users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should get related entities. EF has three patterns used to load related data.

For example, the Include() method works as an implementation of the eager loading pattern.

```
[HttpGet] 
public JsonResult AllBooks() 
{
    var books = _context.Books
        .Include(book => book.Reviews)
        .ToList()
    
    return new JsonResult(Ok(books));
}
```

More information you can get below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/